# Ember property observing objects object-attribute

Tags: ember.js

i am working on a advanced data-model and have to display it in a list.

basically the model has three classes

a list:

```
Application.List = DS.Model.extend({
    modules: DS.hasMany('module', {async: false})
});
```

contains many modules:

```
Application.Module = DS.Model.extend({
    position:        DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 0}),
    module_category: DS.belongsTo('module_category'),
});
```

which belongs to a module category:

```
Application.ModuleCategory = DS.Model.extend({
    position: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 0}),
});
```

The problem is, that the page have to show the lists modules under its categories which are ordered by its position-attribute. Within a category the modules are ordered by its position-attribute too.

```
-> category 1
  - module
-> category 2
  - module
  - module
  ...
```

i managed that using a property which puts the modules into an array (sorted by its positions and category-positions) and adds the category(object) right before its first occurrence. So the first object of the array is always a category (the one with the lowest position) followed by the modules wich belongs to that category

this array is then used by an {{#each}} helper to display.

so far everything works fine.

I also got a drag-and-drop mechanism work so users are able to change position of categorys and modules.

But what does not work is the observer on the position-attributes so the list does not rerender.

```
}.property('model.modules.@each.position', 
    'model.modules.@each.module_category.position'),
```

the first part('model.modules.@each.position') works fine and the list updates itself every time a module got moved.

but the second part ('model.modules.@each.module_category.position') does not work so dragging a category does not force a rerender.

can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I knew I just answered this, but I couldn't find it searching, then found it 5 minutes later, no harm done, search doesn't like looking for `@each`.

Answer (score 0):

@each only works one level deep.  (See the bottom of http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/)  If you need to watch and item deeper pull it up one level.

```
Application.Module = DS.Model.extend({
    position:        DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 0}),
    module_category: DS.belongsTo('module_category'),
    module_category_position: Em.computed.alias('module_category.position')
});
```

And update your property (generally model is in scope so doesn't need to be explicitly stated, but I don't know what your scope is here)

```
}.property('modules.@each.position', 
'modules.@each.module_category_position'),
```

Comment: i am wondering that this does not work for me :/ i checked everything carefully. My application does use a Server-API to load/store lists etc and there is no problem. any changes are saved correctly so it must be the observe of the properties. To save changes on drag'n'drop i add an observer manually to the position attribute which does check for isDirty and then calls the save(). Could this cause the problem?

Comment: would you mind adding the code above which you're talking about?

Comment: i have copied your lines of code without any changes. but they does not work.

Comment: and many thanks for marking this as duplicate and already answered. guess i will not get help anymore...

Comment: at least i found out that it start working when module.get('module_category_position'); is called somewhere. Maybe the computed.alias get activated then or something like that... But think about downvoting you cause my is not a duplicate nor answered anywhere...